# Nodejs binary utility functions library interface design

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, binary

As part of my current employment, I've been working with TCP/TLS in NodeJS for about 2 years. My colleagues and I are using a proprietary binary protocol, for communication between a proprietary hardware device and servers.

Throughout my time working on this project, I wrote functions that handled the conversion and validation of binary data. I found myself rewriting these functions for other projects- and decided it would be a good idea to bundle it as a library.

This is my first time writing TypeScript, and my first time publishing an NPM package... But I thought it'd be good fun, and maybe others will get utility from it too.

The library is called: binary-utility-functions on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/binary-utility-functions) (could probably do with a more creative name in the future), and the question here really is whether or not the interfaces are clean enough.

Example usage:

```
const { validate, convert } = require('binary-utility-functions');

const nibble = 0xF; 
const u8 = 0xAA;
const u16 = 0xBEEF; 
const u32 = 0xDEADBEEF;

validate.nibble(nibble);             // true
validate.u8(u8);                     // true
validate.u16(u16);                   // true
validate.u32(u32);                   // true

validate.nibble(u8);                 // false
validate.u8(u16);                    // false
validate.u16(u32);                   // false

convert.nx2_u8x1(0xA, 0xB);           // 0xAB
convert.u8x1_nx2(0xAB);               // [0xB, 0xA]

convert.u8x2_u16x1(0xAA, 0xBB);       // 0xBBAA
convert.u8x3_u32x1(0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC); // 0xCCBBAA

convert.u16x1_u8x2(0xAABB);           // [0xBB, 0xAA]
convert.u16x2_u32x1(0xBEEF, 0xDEAD);  // 0xDEADBEEF

convert.u32x1_u16x2(0xDEADBEEF);      // 0xBEEFDEAD
```

All conversion functions run the validate functions before execution, to ensure that values are correct.

### Index.ts

```
import {
    is_valid_nibble,
    is_valid_u8,
    is_valid_u16,
    is_valid_u32
} from './validators';

import * as convert_fns from './convert_functions/index';

export const validate = {
    nibble: is_valid_nibble,
    u8: is_valid_u8,
    u16: is_valid_u16,
    u32: is_valid_u32
};

export const convert = { ...convert_fns.default };
```

#### validators.ts

````
/**
  *  This function checks whether a number can safely fit into a nibble (4bits).
  *  If the value is an integer, and it is <= 16 && >= 0, then it can fit into a
  *  nibble.
  *  @example Checking whether values are valid u8 values.
  *  ```
  *  const valid = 0xA;
  *  console.log(validate.nibble(valid))); // true
  *  const invalid = 0xFF;
  *  console.log(validate.nibble(invalid)); // false
  *  ```
  *  @param value - The number to check.
  *  @return boolean
**/
export function is_valid_nibble(value: number): boolean {
    if (Number.isInteger(value) && value <= 0xF && value >= 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
  *  This function checks whether a number can safely fit into an unsigned, 8-bit
  *  integer. If the value is an integer, and it is <= 255 && >= 0, then it can
  *  fit safely into a u8.
  *  @example Checking whether values are valid u16 values
  *  ```
  *  const valid = 0xAB;
  *  const invalid = -1;
  *  console.log(validate.u8(valid));      // true
  *  console.log(validate.u8(invalid));    // false
  *  ```
  *  @param value - The number to check.
  *  @return boolean
**/
export function is_valid_u8(value: number): boolean {
    if (Number.isInteger(value) && value <= 0xFF && value >= 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


/**
  *  This function checks whether a number can safely fit into an unsigned,
  *  16-bit integer. If the value is an integer, and it is <= 0xFFFF && >= 0,
  *  then it can fit safely into a u16.
  *  @example Check whether values are valid u16 values
  *  ```
  *  const valid = 0xBEEF;
  *  const invalid = 0xDEADBEEF;
  *  console.log(validate.u16(valid));     // true
  *  console.log(validate.u16(invalid));   // false
  *  ```
  *  @param  value - The number to check
  *  @return boolean
**/
export function is_valid_u16(value: number): boolean {
    if (Number.isInteger(value) && value <= 0xFFFF && value >= 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}



/**
  *  This function checks whether a number can safely fit into an unsigned,
  *  32-bit integer. If the value is an integer, and it is <= 0xFFFFFFFF && >= 0,
  *  then it can fit safely into a u32.
  *  @example Checking whether values are valid u32 values
  *  ```
  *  const valid = 0xDEADBEEF;
  *  const invalid = 0xDEADBEEF0000BEEF;
  *  console.log(validate.u32(valid));      // true
  *  console.log(validate.u32(invalid));    // false
  *  ```
  *  @param value - The number to check.
  *  @return boolean
**/
export function is_valid_u32(value: number): boolean {
    if (Number.isInteger(value) && value <= 0xFFFFFFFF && value >= 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
````

#### convert_functions/index.ts

```
import {
    two_nibble_to_one_u8,
    one_u8_to_two_nibbles
} from './nibble';

import {
    two_u8_to_one_u16,
    one_u16_to_two_u8 ,
    three_u8_to_one_u32
} from './u8';

import {
    two_u16_to_one_u32,
    one_u32_to_two_u16
} from './u16';

export default {
    nx2_u8x1: two_nibble_to_one_u8,
    u8x1_nx2: one_u8_to_two_nibbles,
    u8x2_u16x1: two_u8_to_one_u16,
    u8x3_u32x1: three_u8_to_one_u32,
    u16x1_u8x2: one_u16_to_two_u8,
    u16x2_u32x1: two_u16_to_one_u32,
    u32x1_u16x2: one_u32_to_two_u16
};
```

#### convert_functions/nibble.ts

````
import { is_valid_nibble, is_valid_u8 } from "../validators";

/**
  * This function takes two numbers, checks whether they're valid nibbles, then
  * combines them together into one, valid unsigned 8-bit integer value.
  * @example Converting two valid nibbles into one u8
  * ```js
  * const left = 0xA;
  * const right = 0xB;
  *
  * const left_right = convert.nx2_u8x1(left, right);
  * console.log(left_right.toString(16));   // 0xAB
  * ```
  * @param nibble_left - The left-most part of the byte.
  * @param nibble_right - The right-most part of the byte.
  * @returns The combination of the two nibbles into one byte.
**/
export function two_nibble_to_one_u8(nibble_left: number, nibble_right: number): number {
    if (! is_valid_nibble(nibble_left) || ! is_valid_nibble(nibble_right)) {
        throw new Error("util::two_nibble_to_one_byte::is_valid_nibble::false");
    }

    return nibble_left << 4 | nibble_right;
}



/**
  * This function takes in a single byte and splits it into two array elements.
  * The returned array contains two nibbles, index 0 is the left-most half,
  * index 1 is the right-most half of the input value,
  *
  * @example Converting one valid u8 into two nibbles
  * ```js
  * const u8 = 0xAB;
  * const [u8_left, u8_right] = convert.u8x1_nx2(u8);
  * console.log(u8_right.toString(16), u8_left.toString(16));
  * // 0xA, 0xB
  * ```
  *
  * @param u8 - The byte that should be split
  * @returns Index 0 = left half, index 1 = right half
**/
export function one_u8_to_two_nibbles(u8: number): [number, number] {
    if (! is_valid_u8(u8)) {
        throw new Error("util::one_u8_to_two_nibbles::is_valid_u8::false");
    }

    return [u8 >> 4, u8 & 0xF];
}
````

#### convert_functions/u8.ts

````
import { is_valid_nibble, is_valid_u8 } from "../validators";

/**
  * This function takes two numbers, checks whether they're valid nibbles, then
  * combines them together into one, valid unsigned 8-bit integer value.
  * @example Converting two valid nibbles into one u8
  * ```js
  * const left = 0xA;
  * const right = 0xB;
  *
  * const left_right = convert.nx2_u8x1(left, right);
  * console.log(left_right.toString(16));   // 0xAB
  * ```
  * @param nibble_left - The left-most part of the byte.
  * @param nibble_right - The right-most part of the byte.
  * @returns The combination of the two nibbles into one byte.
**/
export function two_nibble_to_one_u8(nibble_left: number, nibble_right: number): number {
    if (! is_valid_nibble(nibble_left) || ! is_valid_nibble(nibble_right)) {
        throw new Error("util::two_nibble_to_one_byte::is_valid_nibble::false");
    }

    return nibble_left << 4 | nibble_right;
}



/**
  * This function takes in a single byte and splits it into two array elements.
  * The returned array contains two nibbles, index 0 is the left-most half,
  * index 1 is the right-most half of the input value,
  *
  * @example Converting one valid u8 into two nibbles
  * ```js
  * const u8 = 0xAB;
  * const [u8_left, u8_right] = convert.u8x1_nx2(u8);
  * console.log(u8_right.toString(16), u8_left.toString(16));
  * // 0xA, 0xB
  * ```
  *
  * @param u8 - The byte that should be split
  * @returns Index 0 = left half, index 1 = right half
**/
export function one_u8_to_two_nibbles(u8: number): [number, number] {
    if (! is_valid_u8(u8)) {
        throw new Error("util::one_u8_to_two_nibbles::is_valid_u8::false");
    }

    return [u8 >> 4, u8 & 0xF];
}
````

#### convert_functions/u16.ts

````
import { is_valid_u16, is_valid_u32 } from "../validators";

/**
  * This function converts two, valid 16-bit unsigned integers into one unsigned
  * 32-bit integer.
  * @example Converting two u16 values into one u32
  * ```
  * const left  = 0xDEAD;
  * const right = 0xBEEF;
  *
  * const left_right = convert.u16x2_u32x1(left, right);
  * console.log(left_right.toString(16));
  * // 0xDEADBEEF;
  * ```
  * @param left_u16 - The left-most part of the resultant u32
  * @param right_u16 - The right-most part of the resultant u32
  * @returns A valid u32 value, which is the product of the left & right params.
**/
export function two_u16_to_one_u32(left_u16: number, right_u16: number): number {
    if (! is_valid_u16(left_u16) || ! is_valid_u16(right_u16)) {
        throw new Error("util::two_u16_to_one_u32::is_valid_u16::false");
    }

    // The >>> 0 simply converts a signed number to an unsigned number.
    return (left_u16 << 16 | right_u16) >>> 0;
}



/**
  * This function converts a valid, 32-bit unsigned integer into two 16-bit
  * signed integers.
  * @example Converting one u32 into two u16 values
  * ```
  * const u32 = 0xDEADBEEF;
  * const [ left, right ] = convert.u32x1_u16x2(u32);
  * console.log(left.toString(16), right.toString(16));
  * // [ 0xDEAD, 0xBEEF ]
  * ```
  * @param u32 - The 32-bit unsigned integer to convert
  * @returns An array of two u16s. The left half at index 0, the right at 1
**/
export function one_u32_to_two_u16(u32: number): [number, number] {
    if (! is_valid_u32(u32)) {
        throw new Error("util::one_u32_to_two_u16::is_valid_u32::false");
    }

    return [u32 >>> 16, u32 & 0xFFFF];
}
````

Also, another general question is whether or not it's a good idea to publish d.ts files also? The tsup library said it's not recommended, but I feel like maybe having those types makes it easier to use the library?

Any and all critique welcomed :)